# What's this word I always hear in anime? "Oh no!" or "not good!"

Tags: words, expressions, phrases

Sometimes when a character ends up in a bad situation they'll say a word or phrase that sounds like "matsui!" or "natsui!" It's usually translated as "not good!" or "oh no!" I'm curious as to what the actual word is.

It can be heard at 8:58 in this video
https://youtu.be/RLwo30N0lUI

Comment: So, you are hearing last names when you should be hearing an adjective.

Answer (score 5):

My Japanese is not that good, but I'm pretty sure the word is "mazui" 「まずい」

[不味い](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%8D%E5%91%B3%E3%81%84)

The example 4 fits the situation.